# Matlab: Elegant way to extract (split) array elements

Tags: arrays, matlab, split, range

I have to split, from an array (1D), in blocks of 64, the first element (DC), and another 63 elements (AC) in separate arrays.

I made the UGLY code above:

```
%split DC from AC
n = 8^2;
DC = zigZagLinha(1 : n : end);
AC = blkproc(zigZagLinha, [1 n],'returnsTheOther63');
```

;

```
function array=returnsTheOther63(array64)
    array = array64(2:64);
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?
It's for academic purposes, so, the cleaner, the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply reshape it:

```
res = reshape( zigZagLinha, 64, [] ); % assuming num of elements can be divided by 64 exactly 
% otherwise some padding should be done...
DC = res(1 ,: ); % collect all first elements
AC = res( 2:end, : ); % AC elements
```

Comment: Exactly what I was typing up. +1